# Ubuntu Server on a VM?

Tags: installation, gnome, server, uninstall

I have installed Ubuntu Server on a VM and given it 100 Gb of disk and 2Gb of RAM. I also installed GNOME. My primary reason for the installation was to install a bunch of different NoSQL databases and check them out.  Since my "normal" platform is Windows 7 as was recommended in "Seven Databases in Seven Weeks" it seems easier to have a VM running Linux than having all the utilities to make Windows look like Linux.

Anyway now that I have it installed I am finding that the apps run from the GNOME shell are very slow. Maybe it is just GNOME or Ubuntu-desktop but the applications seem very slow. If the slowness is attributed to the GUI how do I remove them? Once I remove them how is the best way to install various app software? As the only reason that I installed the GUI stuff was to be able to browse to a site and download. If that is possible without the slow GUI then that may be one other reason to remove GNOME and Ubuntu-desktop.

Sorry if these questions are newbie type questions but as Linux is not new to me, the whole Ubuntu distribution is.

Thank you.

Comment: What visualization software do you use? Do you have visualization features enabled in your BIOS and is the VM using them? I suspect your VM is slow in general.

Answer (score 1):

Gnome classic is lighter desktop than unity / Ubuntu Desktop. You can install `gnome-fallback` by using the following command:

```bash
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
```

Then on the login screen, you can select gnome from a list:

[image]

There's aso the [Xfce](http://www.xfce.org/) desktop, it's lighter than gnome, you can download it using this command:

```bash
sudo apt-get install xfce4 xfce4-goodies
```

If you don't want to use any desktop, you can download  software using the command line, using the command `apt-get` will do the work.

Comment: If I use apt-get how do I specify the software that I want. Like for the NoSql case I would like Cassandra, Neo4j, MongoDB, HBase, and Riak. Once I have it set up with a GUI/desktop how do I uninstall the desktop(s) and go back to the terminal prompt?

Comment: you have to search for each program on how to get a repository, just like: http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/DebianPackaging

Comment: All of the sudo commands that you suggest involve a basic terminal window. How do I get back to that? Can I remove what I have installed (both to recover diskspace and to set new boot/login parameters)? Or should I just start the installation of the VM over again?

Comment: Sorry, I've never uninstalled `gnome` or any other desktop in ubuntu server, I could be wrong, but you can try just uninstalling the packages and booting the system normally.

Comment: If  you don't mind two more questions. One, the packaging aside, how do you uninstall something that is installed? Two, If I am to use apt-get to install can I get a list of what can be installed and its version? Thanks again.

Comment: `apt-get remove` will remove a package, for the search, you can use `apt-cache search <program>`. You can also find packages [here](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/).